# Symfony2 - &nbsp sometimes escaped

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm showing a raw title with:

```
{{ title | raw }}
```

This works almost always. But the blank space symbol `&nbsp` is shown in some templates, while all other HTML entities are not escaped.

It seems that it happens when I call render template like this:

```
$this->templating->render('template');
```

While when I render like this:

```
$this->render('template');
```

it is not escaped.

Why is it happening and how should I solve it?

**Edit:**

This is the real line containing the theoretical `title` variable (`community.niceName`):

```
<p>{{ inviter.fullName }}, your {{ memberType }} from {{ community.niceName | raw }}, {{ community.municipality }}, has invited you.</p>
```

Comment: Can you post the entire Twig template?

Comment: @AlbertoFernández - Does it have any relevance?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I asked. But it probably has.

Comment: @AlbertoFernández - I don't think so, but anyway I've added the line where the real variable is rendered (`community.niceName`)

Comment: Are you adding a response object to [`render(...)`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php#L105)? Otherwise you should probably be using [`renderView()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php#L91) instead.